# Does installing more R packages lead to performance issues

Tags: performance, r, installation

If you install more packages in R could this lead to possible performance issues in R? For example if I had 1000 packages installed instead of 10 could loading a package up with:

```
 library('package name')
```

Take a longer time?

Or even other functions in R take a longer time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it should not make a difference.

The number of packages you have installed shouldn't affect the speed of functions or on the loading of a package. Installing the package doesn't put them into RAM or anything, it just installs the files on your harddrive. So the worst thing that could happen is you run out of physical space.

Now if you LOADED all 1000 packages, then you might see a performance hit as that would take up RAM.

Comment: It's not the full story, since there are functions that do traverse the library structure so they will pay a penalty for having many packages. However, there are R core members that have routinely all CRAN packages installed so they typically try to optimize such functions.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek - that is true and a good point, but there is only a small proportion of functions which have that behavior. For the general case, most functions won't suffer from having extra packages installed.

Comment: please note "Or even other functions in R take a longer time?" in the question so, technically, your answer is wrong ;)

Comment: I trust both of your expertise and thank you for giving me this information

Comment: @SimonUrbanek - haha, well can't really argue with that :p. I was thinking more of the general statistics functions that I use regularly in R, none of which (as far as I am aware) access the library structure :S.. but the important thing right now is that Naz has enough info to make an informed decision for whatever he is doing =).

Comment: As an example of other functions that "could" slow down...A call to "installed.packages()" probably takes longer if there are more results.  Of course, this is trivial.  :)